# Convert pixels to points for pdf

Tags: php, pdf, image-processing, fpdf

I am using php and fpdf to generate a pdf. How can I scale a 400 pixel high image to fit in a 300 point high space? The dimensions are just examples, the image and available space are dynamic.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you want to fit 400 pixels in 300 points, then your resizing factor would simply be `300 / 400` = 0.75. You need to put each pixel in 0.75 of a point.

But there is another story you should know:  **Each point is 1/72 of an inch.** and how many pixels make 1 inch is a *matter of choice*.

All images have a property called DPI: dots per inch. It specifies how many pixels are there for each inch of the picture. So if you want to convert a 400px * 400px picture to a (say) 96 dpi image, your resizing factor will be `400 / ((72 / 96) * 400)`. 72 here is for converting inches to points.

Comment: Agreed, I explained it badly. I think your first sentence answers my question. In my original question I did not know wheteher the user was using 72dpi or 96dpi(or anything else).

Comment: I think it is how many pixels make up an inch is a matter of choice.

Comment: You're right, I edited. But imagine a world where a single pixel is bigger than an inch, then we can talk about how many inches make one pixel. Why not? :)

Answer (score 0):

You can resize the picutre first with [imagecopyresampled](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php).

-> [Basic Example](http://www.white-hat-web-design.co.uk/blog/resizing-images-with-php/)
-> [Adding image to pdf](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/image.htm)

Comment: I can resize the image but I do not know how to convert pixels to points, not knowing what the users system is set to.

Comment: What's the problem in using image?

Comment: If the image is smaller than 300 points I do not want resize it. If it is larger I need to resize it. And all I have is pixels to test that. I also may need to resize X or Y depending on if the image is taller or wider. I see 96 dpi in the image function, should I covert using 96dpi? Or is that an assumption I should not make?